# NIC failed, "This device cannot start"

Tags: networking

PC was working fine until I plugged a Powerline adapter in elsewhere in the house (could be completely unrelated and wholly coincidental of course, but seems unlikely!). 
Now, my network card (which is on-board on my Mobo) is failing and the network adapter has vanished completely from Windows 10. If I delve into device manager I can see an exclamation mark next to the Ethernet controller and double clicking gives the error under device status:

```
This device cannot start (Code 10).
The network address used in the request is invalid.
```

Googling hasn’t been much help. I’ve uninstalled the device, disabled/enabled it and rebooted the machine several times but nothing is working.

[image]
[image]

Any suggestions on what could be the cause of this and how I can fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Go to device manager, uninstall the NIC device, then refresh PC, the driver should be automatically added.

Answer (score 2):

Did you run into this after a Fast Ring update by any chance?

I had a similar issue yesterday and was able to solve it by manually installing the [drivers from Realtek](http://www.realtek.com.tw/Downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&Langid=1&Level=5&PFid=5&PNid=13). I guess there was something wrong with the automatically installed driver or the Windows update corrupted it.

Of course, if there is no other NIC in your PC, you'll first need to download the drivers onto a USB key or something from a different machine.

Comment: Ran into this after a slow ring update. Thanks for the link, updating the drivers worked a treat.

Answer (score 0):

for those having this problem and find this post. In my case simple reboot worked! Seems like NIC might not work right after installing into motherboard but may start working after first reboot.